# when can we hold all the objects that we are ever created-ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I have read this "keep holding on to all the objects you’ve ever created,then ARC will never be able to release them".I didn't understand this.Can someone explain this scenario with example when can we hold all the objects we created.

Comment: Please provide a link to that statement.

Comment: If you want your code to run like this, simply use manual reference counting and never release anything. Then go and get a different job ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Object is alive as long as it is not deallocated and thus its memory is freed. With manual reference counting you had to call a release for each retain until the retainCount reaches 0. With ARC the compiler insert releases automatically depending on the variable weak/strong type.

So, to hold onto an object it needs to be

- defined as strong
- another living object needs to hold a
  reference onto it

As long as you have a reference to an object and it is not defined as weak, it will live.

A good introduction and explanation can be found for example at [Mike Ash blog](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html).

Comment: don't ask questions in an answer! Use the comments under the questions.

Comment: @volker,It is general question asked for understanding ARC.

Comment: and My question is When can this happen in ARC.

Answer (score 1):

"Keep holding" objects means here to never release them (i.e. keep a reference in a variable, list etc.). Because these objects are not released (decrease their reference count) they cannot be removed by the release pool and consume memory for the entire lifetime of the application. If you create more such objects you will sooner or later run out of available memory and your application will crash.

With manual reference counting it was quite easy to forget to release objects properly so they were kept in memory, even though not used at all.

With ARC this has changed as the reference count is automatically increased/decreased (and the object freed when this count reaches 0).

Comment: You can also create strong or weak pointers by declaring them in your header file (e.g. "@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *string")

Comment: I didn't understand why the guys are giving down votes.What are you going to get with that?

Comment: I am not asking the question for votes,asking to gain some knowledge.